# Find Out How to Get Data in Firebase's Android Studio (There are many hierarchies)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing my small app. Today,
I'm having trouble getting data from my Firebase.

Here is my Firebase structure:

[image]

This is modal Request:

```
public class Request {
    //    private String phone, name, address, total, status;
    private String phone, name, address, status;
    private int total;
    private List<Order> foods;

    public Request() {
    }

    public Request(String phone, String name, String address, int total, List<Order> foods) {
        this.phone = phone;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.total = total;
        this.foods = foods;
        this.status = "0"; //Default 0. 0: place, 1: shipping, 2: shipped
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<Order> getFoods() {
        return foods;
    }

    public void setFoods(List<Order> foods) {
        this.foods = foods;
    }
}
```

I obtained the Order data by going to "PhoneNumber" and getting the
 "ID Order" data as follows:

```
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_status);

        //Firebase:
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        requests = database.getReference("Requests");

        //init:
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_orderview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadOrders(Common.currentUser.getPhone());
       //Common.currentUser.getPhone() This is PhoneNumber current
    }

private void loadOrders(final String phone) {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Request, OrderViewHolder>(
                Request.class,
                R.layout.order_item,
                OrderViewHolder.class,
                requests.child(phone) // I have access to "PhoneNumber" 
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OrderViewHolder viewHolder, Request model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                viewHolder.txtOrderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
                viewHolder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());
                viewHolder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
                viewHolder.txtOrderTotal.setText(String.valueOf(model.getTotal()));

                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
//                        Get CategoryID and send Activity Foods List:
                        Intent moveToOrderDetails = new Intent(OrderStatusActivity.this, OrderDetailsActivity.class);
                        moveToOrderDetails.putExtra("KeyOrder", adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                        startActivity(moveToOrderDetails);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And this is my Apdapter:

```
public class OrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

    public TextView txtOrderId, txtOrderStatus, txtOrderPhone, txtOrderAddress, txtOrderTotal;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public OrderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtOrderId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
        txtOrderStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_status);
        txtOrderPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_phone);
        txtOrderAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_address);
        txtOrderTotal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_total);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
        contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Select the action");
        contextMenu.add(0, 0, getAdapterPosition(), Common.UPDATE);
        contextMenu.add(0, 1, getAdapterPosition(), Common.DELETE);
    }
}
```

And now I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the data of all
 orders without having to go to "Number Phone". I tried to think and
 perform but failed.

This is image demo about an order:

[image]

Comment: can you share your firebase database

Comment: So you want to get the data under foods without knowing the phone number?

Comment: Yes. I want to see all orders of all customers.

Comment: I need help please

Comment: Under foods, there are two childs, this what you want to get? Please responde with @AlexMamo